# How Did Tony Stark Recover the Mark I Armor?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-2

In Iron Man (1), Tony is shown escaping the terrorist camp in the Mark I armor.  He crash lands in the desert, and leaves the scraps of armor there.  In fact, the terrorists are shown recovering it later in the film.

In Iron Man II, however, the Mark I armor is shown in the armor "gallery" in his house in Malibu.  How did he recover the Mark I armor?  Was that ever addressed?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just a holograph? Check the picture below. The light beams make it look like it might be one.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Sequence of events, all which took place on screen in the Iron Man (1) movie:

- Tony escapes with the armor and crashes in the desert.
- Raza (the terrorist leader) recovers the armor from the desert.
- Obadiah Stane recovers the armor from Raza and brings it back to Stark Industries to try to recreate it.
- Agent Coulson and Pepper Potts enter Stark Industries, find the Mark I, and are promptly attacked by Iron Monger (Obidiah Stane).

Since the Mark I was at Stark Industries, Tony was in a position to just acquire it and move it to his estate after the events of Iron Man (1).

Comment: The armor was literally in the same building (or the next building over) as Tony's office by the end.

Comment: Wasn't that building blown up?

Comment: Even if Tony didn't get the armor directly from Stane's lab, he still would have probably gotten it back from S.H.I.E.L.D., assuming they went over the lab with a fine-tooth comb following the fight with Iron Monger. It was in pieces, and wasn't the whole suit, which is probably why it showed as RECONSTRUCTION in the suit gallery.

Answer (score 14):

From Iron Man 2 after Tony returns from DC. [image]

The word "Reconstruction" is (just) readable above the Mark I armor.

Comment: Great job :) But you should add a description/explanation of what this means. Frankly I think you should have simply edited this image into user28639's answer...

Answer (score 4):

In one of the scenes where Tony's lab is visible through VR overlay (if I remember correctly it was his helmet HUD), all armours have overlaid labels. Mark I is described as reconstruction or something of that sort.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot, or know which movie that is in?

Answer (score -1):

I've been rewatching the MCU and just randomly thought of this, hense why I'm 6 years late to this thread lmfao
But ok that would make sense, he reconstructed it for the armor gallery

I was confused because plenty of his suits get destroyed and I guess he rebuilds them cheaply, out of boredome and a coping mechanism, which in IM3 I think it is he says he's not the sentimental type, which is why he told Pepper to throw his old Arc Reactor away but she didn't which turned into his favor when his new one got ripped out of his chest.
Which I always thought was just odd as to why he'd rebuild his old suits if he doesn't care about sentiment.

But if he's doing it when he's not working on upgrades and what not to help cope with past trauma then that would make sense.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You seem to be undermining your own hypothesis instead of building it up.  That he would do it to cope with trauma seems a bit of a stretch, considering he's quite capable of not dealing with trauma in so many ways, so you'll need to give a bit of support for the idea that building old, obsolete artifacts could be helpful for him.